# is it possible to load virtual machine to memory like that of a live cd

Tags: virtualization, xen, kvm-virtualization

Can we create and run a virtual machine that uses RAM only or minimized HDD usage.

**That is same as the working concept  as that of live  CD.**

I know It is possible,but still confused,whether it can be implemented.

Comment: yes if you have a live cd iso boot it, done!

Comment: But in that case how can we configure network,sharing network bridge.
Vm should be loaded into the memory that is what that needs to done.

Comment: just like any live cd does there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: This is nothing to do with virtualisation really. You either have enough ram assigned to your computer (whether real or virtual) that is hosting the OS, or you don't. And the OS you're using is either able to work in that way you want or it isn't.

Comment: I want my VM to use only RAM instead of HDD that is the requirement.I know data will not be persistent.Required Data will be configured to save in HDD.Doesnt it reduce CPU i/o wait on HDD.We are planning to run 6 vms.so to avoid bottleneck with HDD,it seems the best option.Do u have any other option.Kindly share it with me.

Comment: Nothing magical happens just because someone said "Virtualisation". Remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sufficient ram, create a large tmpfs ram drive and put your hard drive images there.

Just like a live cd things will be lost when the system crashes or reboots. You will probably need scripts that sync it to a real drive on a regular basis and before shutting down.

Why are you trying to minimize hard drive use? That might help figure out the best solution.

Comment: we are having a machine with many cpu cores and good RAM.But with 2 HDD only.So inorder to reduce the cost of buying new machines,we want this machine to be virtualized into 6 VM,and All the data will be written into a real HDD.From my understanding sharing 2 HDD among 6 VM can cause serious bottleneck.Can you help me in loading VM to RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion that it is possible to create a VM that uses RAM only.that information is very helpful.Thanx alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are several distributions out there that are geared towards this operating model.  They typically have a LiveCD to boot from (or boot from USB media) and store things like configuration parameters, home directories, files, etc. on a USB drive.  There is no reason why you couldn't run this in a VM just as easily (you wouldn't need a USB drive, just a very small disk partition to store the relevant data).

See http://www.desktoplinux.com/articles/AT8963693541.html for some examples (note, this page is about seven years old and the links on it may not work any more, but you can always search for the distros described).